# Showing children of current subspaces in confluence

Tags: spaces, confluence

I'm using the confluence subspaces plugin, and on each of the space homes pages I would like to show the children of the current space.

The markup used for setting the Default Space Content specifies that {0} can be used to get the space name, but I need to get the space key in here. Is there any way to do that in the Default Space Content (without editing the underlying velocity template)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the children macro, the children of the space appear without having to specify the space key:

```
    This is the home page for the {spacename} space.
    {children:depth=2}
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce, we were looking for way to not have to manually specify the depth. Either way, we've stopped using the subspaces plugin, but thanks.